# NodeJS Performance Issue

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm running an API server using NodeJS 6.10.3 LTS on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty). I've noticed that my API server tops out at ~600 reqs/min running on a c4.large EC2 instance. By tops out I mean, I see the CPU go uptil 100% Note, I know that I'm not fully utilizing the instance by using the cluster module, but that's ok for now.

I took a .cpuprofile dump of my API server for 10 seconds, and  noticed that every second, for ~300ms, the profiler shows my NodeJS code is sitting (idle).

Does anyone know what that (idle) implies? Is it a GC issue? Or is it a internal (to V8) lock that I'm triggering? Any help or pointers to tools to help debug this would be nice. I'm working on anonymizing some of stack traces in the cpuprofile so I can share.

The packages I'm using are ExpressJS 4, Couchbase NodeJS SDK, Socket.IO mainly. The codepaths are mainly reading requests, and pushing to Couchbase. And finally querying couchbase via Views API, and pushing some aggregated data on a Socket.IO channel. So all pretty I/O async friendly stuff. I've made sure that I'm not calling any synchronous functions. There are no patterns of function calls before the (idle) in the cpu profile.

Comment: Sorry I don't have more, but this talk was really helpful when I ran into Node perf problems: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1YP8QP9gLA

Comment: If the server goes idle and you aren't using any synchronous I/O,  then you apparently are not saturating the CPU (not keeping the server fully busy) or your server is just not CPU bound and something else (likely the disk or DB) is your bottleneck.

Comment: @jfriend00 actually one of my CPU's core does stay up at 100% usage in the test. But I still see these (idle)'s every second.

Answer (score 0):

It could also just be I/O wait, meaning none of the sockets have data ready to read yet and so the time is spent idle. If you are using a load testing library you should check that the requests are evenly distributed within a second.

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gc-stats to check GC data. There are flags to increase heap space, and to change when GC runs, if the problem turns out to be GC related.